# How to upload multiple files on plunker or How to connect my github repository to Plunker

Tags: angularjs, plunker

Trying to upload AngularJS project on Plunker, but I could not find any option to upload multiple files and folders or I could also not find how to import the project from GitHub Repository so that I can upload the AngularJS project and have a share-able link.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: See the link https://javaiq2018.blogspot.com/2017/10/file-upload-example-in-jersey-and.html

Comment: Using https://next.plnkr.co/edit/, you can simply drag a folder or a set of files from your desktop into the file tree. Note that you should drop these on the "Project" entry to make this work.